# Warning when getting out

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

When I get out of the program
 This alert shows

What is this error about?

> Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.example.hp.myapplication23.CustomList) [Instantiatable]

These are my codes :

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final  Activity context;
    private final String[] name ;
    private final String[] gen ;
    private final Integer[] img ;


    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] name , String[] gen , Integer[] img) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_list,name );


        this.context = context;
        this.name = name ;
        this.gen = gen ;
        this.img = img ;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater infalter = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View v = infalter.inflate(R.layout.custom_list , null , true);

        TextView txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtGen = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gen);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        txtName.setText(name[position]);
        txtGen.setText(gen[position]);
        image.setImageResource(img[position]);

        return v ;








    }


}
```

please guide me

Comment: Did you list that class in the manifest?

Comment: No! this class for Custom Listview

Comment: Yeah, that class doesn't need a zero-argument constructor, but the only time I've seen that warning for a non-component class is when something gets listed in the manifest that's not supposed to be there.

Comment: Thank you very much for resolving your issue